# SPD PD-M520 Pedals, replacing the Body Cover

Tags: shimano, spd

I have taken the body cover off my Shimano PD-M520 pedals and am unable to get it back on due to a little nodule having to be behind the bit of metal where the tightness ajustment is. That part is very stiff to move the correct amount! I was wondering if theres a knack to it or if brute force has to prevail here? First Picture shows the body cover not on properly, (I never knew it was called a body cover until I checked out Shimano's schematic for the pedal!) the second picture shows the nodule thing im talking about (Im full of technical terms)
[image: on]

[image: off]

Thanks!

Comment: Got to ask.  Why did you take it off?

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this one :P I wanted to put the flats on one side, as my girlfriend who hates the idea of SPDs wanted to use my bike, and I thought that would be quicker than pedals switch... clever me thought to get the flats on, instead of looking for the manual, I would unscrew that and screw it back on 1 min job... but I have now turned my brain on and fixed it!

Comment: THE FIX:
I used a monkey wrench to lock onto the springy bit which gave me something to grip and a longer lever and it was super easy.... I need to use my brain more often... :P

I always find I spend hours stuck on something then as soon as I publicly ask for help thats it, my brain goes oh Ill work now!!

Comment: Got to vote that up based entertainment value.  After you put the flat on just how did you plan to get access to those screws?

Comment: I'm guessing the right fix was to unscrew it some more and assemble the thing back in the correct order.

Answer (score 2):

I remember doing this last year. You need a way to keep the spring-loaded part (on the left in your pictures) out of the way while you move the other part into the correct position where you can attach the screw. If I remember correctly, I did this by sticking a long screwdriver between the axle and the spring-loaded part and holding it with one hand while using the other hand to position the loose part and putting at least one screw in to hold it.